# Same return type like callback

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I created a generic error handler wrapper function which handles errors in case there are some and returns the result of the callback. My problem is that typescript doesn't allow me to return a Promise because

```
TS2322: Type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'R'.
   'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Promise<unknown>'
```

That's my function

```
export function withErrorHandler<R>(action: string, callback: () => R): R {
  function isPromise<X>(promise: Promise<X> | unknown): promise is Promise<X> {
    return promise instanceof Promise;
  }
  try {
    const result = callback();

    if (isPromise(result)) {
      return result.catch(error => {
        handleError(error, action);
        throw error;
      });
    }

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error, action);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Who knows how to write the generics to infer the return type and allow it to return either Promise when the callback returns a Promise or return non-Promise?
Thx <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler cannot verify that `result.catch(...)` returns a `Promise` that's the same exact type as `result`.  For example, for all the compiler knows, `result` is a `Promise` with extra properties, and while `result.catch` will definitely be a `Promise`, it might not have these same extra properties.  And this can actually happen and lead to runtime errors:

```
const promiseWithCheese = Object.assign(Promise.resolve(10), { cheese: "cheddar" });
const weh = withErrorHandler("x", () => promiseWithCheese);
try {
    weh.cheese.toUpperCase(); //accepted at compile time, but
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e); //  weh.cheese is undefined
}
```

I assume that this is unlikely and you don't want to worry about it.  If so, then the easiest thing for you to do is just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `result.catch()` has the same type as `result`:

```
if (isPromise(result)) {
    return result.catch(error => {
        // handleError(error, action);
        throw error;
    }) as (typeof result);
}
```

Now the compiler won't warn about mismatch between `R` and `Promise<unknown>`, because you've told it that `result.catch()` returns something like `R & Promise<unknown>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.4.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdxlAFgUQE7btgCQEMwATAGwFNsAeAJQD4AKI6eMALkQGcpsYwAcwA0iCEXLkARqwDWXJgEpEAXgaI6irnUQBvAFD7ExxKEiwEiGNwAKeALbXKTAA4OnXcLLBxkYLYhucI7clFbciHbBTjRePn7qBibJiNiUUCDYSEEhYQK8JBCUcMCR7qEA3EYmAL7VxnwAnnr1KRAIvKmU3CDkUKpiEtJySlWtyTClTNZRuUxpPX2Kykkpa2kZWV2LUAB04lAQ6EzUeNiqieNrKQD0N4joJBSUOGcnuPiirBb+Vdf-iAweGQiFO+D+AOMNWURAiTCgjRcxVKC16UEUELWdSuxg2mSQqL6mMQNUGh3QiHeZxWOMQdweTyor3wVM+iG+7AxtKBvlBH2wxLq2P07TAnRyTgA6mh0ABhdCUbphFSIADyUgAVpRoLtYdwYIIwExZk5dgs4OQAG7OACMAAZFKJdGIFUquAAiI6UUikIjYd0krmizrISgUlWoDDMwiM6hMd0AD3doiUF0C5Uo0ow8sVoS5TRayVD6H2rtCuygcAAqi4kdhZbDnBi6TdWEUXFBvez+u17C4YFRATB7JRRFIQFB9KSDkdKZQaclgxbKLtyHBBCdm-TALwbgFKdlBh0u5vIRcCkSjAATeqeGQxAA)

Comment: Awesome, thank you <3. It's actually quite obvious after your explanation.